# x=*ptr++; is equivalent to x=*ptr; ptr=ptr+1;?

Tags: c, pointers, post-increment

In the below code

```
ptr1--->ptr--->&c=4
```

when i print *ptr and **ptr1 both prints value of c i.e 4 everything is fine here, but after initialization of x with *ptr++, i read somewhere

that x=*ptr++ is equivalent to x=*ptr; ptr= ptr+1;

if it's true that means pointer ptr is pointing to a new address but still *ptr and **ptr1 prints the value of c why?

```
int main(void)
{
    int x, c=4, *ptr=&c,**ptr1=&ptr;
    printf("\nBefore incrementation ptr points to c\n%p == %p", ptr,&c);
    x=*ptr++;
    printf("\n%d,%d,%d,%p,%p,%p\n\n", x,*ptr,**ptr1,&c,ptr,ptr1); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: After `ptr++` the pointer no longer points `c` and dereferencing the pointer results in [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). So the code is allowed to print anything it wants, including 4.

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that, after the increment `ptr` is now pointing at `x`... Try doubling either `c` or `x` before printing... Report the results...

Comment: but it happens only with x=*ptr++; but if do *ptr++; then now *ptr prints a garbage value

Comment: Initialise 'x' with a "non-garbage" value: ` int x = 42, c = ...`

Comment: @SupportUkraine i know it works fine with arrays but with a single variable things look different

Comment: (Probably compiler-dependent) If you change the last print to `printf("\n%p,%d,%d,%d,%p,%p,%p\n\n", &x, x,*ptr,**ptr1,&c,ptr1,ptr1);`, what will happen? I see that `*ptr` and `**ptr1` have garbage values rather than '4'.

Comment: (Probably compiler-dependent) One odd thing is that if I add `&x;` after `return 0;`, even though it's unreachable, it makes `*ptr` and `**ptr1` have garbage values.

Comment: @Fe2O3 ptr is pointing to  x but why?

Comment: Stack allocation, it's normal for neighboring variables to occupy memory spaces next to each other (but I don't think it's guaranteed)

Comment: "... but why?"... Funny question to ask on "Stack Overflow"....

Comment: Before the last printing: 
1. If I add `*ptr += 14;` then it's 18 18 18;
2. If I add `*ptr += 14; &x;` 4 garbage garbage. 
3. If I add `*ptr *= 14;` then it's 56 56 56;
4. If I add `*ptr *= 14; &x;` program fails to finish properly.
Such is the oddity of undefined behavior for this particular compiler.

Comment: 1. If I add *ptr += 14; then it's 18 18 18; 2. If I add *ptr += 14; &x; 18,18,18. 3. If I add *ptr *= 14; then it's 56 56 56; 4. If I add *ptr *= 14; &x; 56,56,56 program finish properly@qrsngky

Answer (score 1):

DO NOT DO THIS under normal circumstances... This 'happily' exploits "undefined behaviour" with the code generated by my C compiler. This is BAD PRACTICE, but useful to understand the behaviour you experienced.

```
int main() {
    int x = 123;
    int y = 456;
    int z = 789;
    int *p = &y; // 'p' points at stack variable 'y'...

    printf( "%d %d %d\n", p[-1], p[0], p[1] );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
789 456 123
```

I repeat: This is for educational purposes only.

Comment: Undefined behavior is such that... same code, different compiler: `0 456 123`. 
After inserting `&x;` somewhere in the code: `123 456 789`.

Comment: output : 49 456 1033893452 same code different compiler

Comment: Same code, yet another compiler: 0 456 0

Comment: I left it running on mine, but when I returned there was no computer. Just a swirl of leaves.

Comment: @WeatherVane UB will do that to you... :-)  Welcome to Narnia...

Comment: @WeatherVane  may be thanos snapped his fingers and turn ur  computer into leaves

Answer (score 0):

My environment : WSL2 with gcc9.3
I add two value to printf to show the address of local variables:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        int x, c=4, *ptr=&c,**ptr1=&ptr;
        printf("Before incementation ptr points to c\n%p == %p\n", ptr,&c);
        x=*ptr++;
        printf("ptr:%p\n", ptr);
        printf("x:%d\n*ptr:%d\n**ptr1:%d\n&c:%p\nptr:%p\nptr1:%p\n&ptr:%p\n&ptr1:%p\n",
                        x, *ptr, **ptr1, &c, ptr, ptr1, &ptr, &ptr1);
        return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
Before incementation ptr points to c
0x7fffe4ffe0d0 == 0x7fffe4ffe0d0
ptr:0x7fffe4ffe0d4
x:4
*ptr:4
**ptr1:4
&c:0x7fffe4ffe0d0
ptr:0x7fffe4ffe0d4
ptr1:0x7fffe4ffe0d8
&ptr:0x7fffe4ffe0d8
&ptr1:0x7fffe4ffe0e0
```

Note that? The "ptr" is adjacent to "c" on stack. So after "x=*ptr++", "ptr" pointing to itself.

> if it's true that means pointer ptr is pointing to a new address but still *ptr and **ptr1 prints the value of c why?

So you can see that "ptr" does not pointing to c.

The next problem is when does "*ptr" changed, I'am single-instruction tracing the code, I found it is changed in a piece of pre-call asm-code:

```
119b:       48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
119f:       48 8d 55 e0             lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rdx
11a3:       48 89 c6                mov    %rax,%rsi
11a6:       48 8d 3d 5b 0e 00 00    lea    0xe5b(%rip),%rdi        # 2008 <_IO_stdin_used+0x8>
11ad:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
11b2:       e8 b9 fe ff ff          callq  1070 <printf@plt>
    x=*ptr++;
11b7:       48 8b 45 e8             mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
11bb:       48 8d 50 04             lea    0x4(%rax),%rdx
11bf:       48 89 55 e8             mov    %rdx,-0x18(%rbp)
11c3:       8b 00                   mov    (%rax),%eax
11c5:       89 45 e4                mov    %eax,-0x1c(%rbp)
    printf("ptr:%p\n", ptr);
```

At address 11c5 the value changed, but I'm not good at compiler, so I don't know what does those instructions exactly mean.

Comment: in line 4, print address of ptr instead of printing address of which ptr is pointing. printf("\n ptr : %p", &ptr);

Comment: @xan_003 I wrote that line to show the change of "ptr" after "x=*ptr++", "&ptr" is printed the next line, and since its address can't be changed so no need to print again.

Answer (score 0):

@g11de see this code

```
    int main(void)
    {
        int x, c=4, *ptr=&c,**ptr1=&ptr;
        printf("\nBEFORE INCREMENTATION\n\n");
        printf("&x = %p\n&c = %p\n&ptr = %p\nptr ---> %p\n&ptr1 = %p\nptr1 ---> %p\n",&x,&c,&ptr,ptr,&ptr1,ptr1);
        x=*ptr++;
        printf("\n\nAFTER INCREMENTATION\n\n");
        printf("x : %d\n*ptr : %d\n**ptr1 : %d\n&c : %p\nptr : %p\nptr1 : %p\n&ptr : %p\n&ptr1 : %p\n",x,*ptr,**ptr1,&c,ptr,ptr1,&ptr,&ptr1);
        x=*ptr++;
        printf("\n\nAFTER INCREMENTATION\n\n");
        printf("x : %d\n*ptr : %d\n**ptr1 : %d\n&x : %p\nptr : %p\nptr1 : %p\n&ptr : %p\n&ptr1 : %p\n",x,*ptr,**ptr1,&x,ptr,ptr1,&ptr,&ptr1);
        return 0;
    }
```

before incrementation **pointer ptr points to --->&c = 000000f6b19ff858** and **address is &ptr = 000000f6b19ff850** after incrementation pointer points to a new address
**ptr--->000000f6b19ff85c** and address of ptr **&ptr = 000000f6b19ff850** both are different that means ptr is pointing to somewhere else i.e **ptr is pointing to x**

```
BEFORE INCREMENTATION

&x = 0000001e33bff7fc
&c = 0000001e33bff7f8
&ptr = 0000001e33bff7f0
ptr ---> 0000001e33bff7f8
&ptr1 = 0000001e33bff7e8
ptr1 ---> 0000001e33bff7f0


AFTER INCREMENTATION

x : 4
*ptr : 4
**ptr1 : 4
&x : 0000001e33bff7fc
ptr : 0000001e33bff7fc
ptr1 : 0000001e33bff7f0
&ptr : 0000001e33bff7f0
&ptr1 : 0000001e33bff7e8


AFTER INCREMENTATION

x : 4
*ptr : -58387552
**ptr1 : -58387552
&x : 0000001e33bff7fc
ptr : 0000001e33bff800
ptr1 : 0000001e33bff7f0
&ptr : 0000001e33bff7f0
&ptr1 : 0000001e33bff7e8
```

see this after first incrementation

```
&x : 000000f6b19ff85c
ptr : 000000f6b19ff85c
&ptr = 000000f6b19ff850
```

see this after second incrementation

```
*ptr : -58387552
&x : 0000001e33bff7fc
ptr : 0000001e33bff800
&ptr : 0000001e33bff7f0
```

that means pointer incrementation works on formula
**ptr ---> ptr + sizeof(datatype) * i**